# IT Considerations for a company name change

Tags: infrastructure, best-practices

Nothing is "for sure" yet but there is a good chance my company will be changing it's name in the future.

Our IT requirements are relatively modest - Exchange server, IIS, MSSQL, etc.

My question is, what kind of considerations need to be made before changing a company name in the world of IT? Obviously our domain name will be changing, which means some work in Exchange but can anybody think of any thing else?

I feel as though this is almost too simple. The reason I'm asking is because if anything is beyond my skill level we'll need to contract out an IT consultant which would require me to accommodate for that in future budgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few absolutes and a few maybe's, depending on your perspective:

You'll need to configure Exchange to be authoritative for the new domain name if you want to recieve email using the new domain name, you'll need to setup\reconfigure your external DNS to reflect the new domain name (A records, MX records, etc.), you'll need to create\change your external web site to reflect the new domain name, etc., etc. These are a few of the things I see as being absolutes.

A few of the maybe's might relate to changing your internal domain name and naming convention, depending on how it's currently configured and what the "powers that be" want it to be. If your internal domain name and naming convention reflects the old company name and everyone is OK with leaving it as it is going forward, then there's nothing to do. If not, then you've got some work to do internally as well.

Comment: You've likely thought of this but your REgistration Authority for SSL certificates that your company might use (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, domain change, which, depending on your Exchange setup, may involve some Active Directory work as well.

A simple approach for this would be to maintain your existing AD domain name internally, even if it does reference your old company name, and assign additional SMTP addresses to mailboxes for your Internet addressing.

You need to talk to your ISP regarding MX records for inbound e-mail delivery.

Don't forget things like e-mail footers, Web site branding, Etc.  I'm guessing all your contractual T's and C's will be handled by your legal/procurement peeps?